# How would you add a delete and edit function to the Address book program?

Tags: java, javafx

So i am practicing TableView through this example: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm

I understand everything in it, except I wanted to extend it further and include a delete and edit function as well. Could somebody please help me!? I've been trying for a while now but nothing seems to be working.

This is my add function (which works):

```
@FXML
    protected void addMusic(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        ObservableList<Music> data = tableView.getItems();
        data.add(new Music(albumField.getText(),
                songField.getText(),
                genreField.getText()
        ));

        albumField.setText("");
        songField.setText("");
        genreField.setText("");
    }
```

my Delete function which doesn't work:

```
      @FXML
    protected void deleteMusic(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        ObservableList<Music> data = tableView.getItems();
        data.remove(new Music(albumField.deleteText(),
                songField.deleteText(),
                genreField.deleteText()
        ));

    }


        }
```

Thanks

Changed deleteMusic:

```
 @Override
    protected void deleteMusic(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        ObservableList<Music> data = tableView.getItems();
        data.remove(equals(Music(albumField.deleteText(), songField.deleteText(), genreField.deleteText());

        albumField.setText("");
        songField.setText("");
        genreField.setText("");

    }
```

Music class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;



public class Music {
    private final SimpleStringProperty album = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty song = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty genre = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Music() {
        this("", "", "");
    }

    public Music(String album, String song, String genre) { //Constructor utilised
        setAlbum(album);
        setSong(song);
        setGenre(genre);
    }


    public String getAlbum() {
        return album.get();
    }

    public void setAlbum(String sAlbum) {
        album.set(sAlbum);
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song.get();
    }

    public void setSong(String sAlbum) {
        song.set(sAlbum);
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre.get();
    }

    public void setGenre(String sAlbum) {
        genre.set(sAlbum);
    }


}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SoWs.png

Comment: Does `Music` override `equals`?

Comment: You're creating a new Music object, not grabbing an existing one, so if you haven't overridden equals() to check for data equality instead of object reference equality, it'll never find the object you're trying to delete.

Comment: @azurefrog I'm sorry I dont get it could you show me please?

Comment: data.remove(Override equals(Music(albumField.deleteText(), songField.deleteText(), genreField.deleteText())));

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I don't understand how to do it. I want to be able to click/highlight the row in the table and then delete.

Comment: It's not a method call, it's a method you need to @Override on the Music class itself.

Comment: It's really impossible to read code in a comment.  If you have something you want to add to your question, please edit the original question and add the code there.

Comment: @azurefrog sure I understand - i have moved it! could you please help me, it's throwing an error

Comment: Please post the `Music` class. You need to override the `equals` method of your `Music` class, not some method of your controller class.

Comment: The equals method isn't something that goes in `deleteMusic()`, or in your Table View at all.  It's something you need to add to the Music class itself.  Go edit Music.java and add the method there.

Comment: I have added the Music class. Which method should I alter and add equals () to?Thank you for your help till now.

Comment: You should alter no methods.  `equals()` is a **new** method you need to add to `Music`.  Most modern IDEs have a way to automatically generate `equals()` and `hashCode()`.  What are you using to build your project?

Comment: ...For the record, these comments have gotten seriously off-topic. OP, try reading an intermediate OOP tutorial -- they tend to cover this kind of thing. I'd link one if I could find any decent ones, but I don't have my list anymore.

Comment: I'm using intelliJ, so i'll just put a new blank method like public void equals(){ }??

Comment: See JetBrains help [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html).

Comment: Oh okay!! Thank you :) - now in the controller class method for musicDelete should I just leave it?

Comment: it's not working if I just leave it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most java `Collection`s use the equals method to check, if 2 objects are considered to be the same. If the elements of a collection don't override `equals`, no 2 different objects are considered to be equal, even if they contain equal values in their fields.

You could override `equals` like this:

```
...
import java.util.Objects;

public class Music {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // make sure equals is symetric
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Music other = (Music) obj;
        // compare strings for equality
        return Objects.equals(this.getAlbum(), other.getAlbum())
                && Objects.equals(this.getSong(), other.getSong())
                && Objects.equals(this.getGenre(), other.getGenre());
    }

}
```

You could then use

```
data.remove(new Music(albumField.getText(), songField.getText(), genreField.getText()));
```

to remove a `Music` object from the list.

Comment: thanks for this!! What should i do to the musicDelete method?

Comment: also, how would I carry out the edit function? thank you sooo much for your help!! sorry for troubling you

Comment: @april21: sorry, of course you need to use the same methods as in your `addMusic` methods to get the text from your text fields. BTW: I don't recommend starting with javafx until you understood the basic java tutorials. UI programming is a bit advanced and certainly not the place to start learning java.... But I'd do editing basically like this: Allow the user to select a line, get the selected `Music` object, and change the properties in that object (there should be listeners taking care of the ui update when the properties change; otherwise you need to notify the ui that a change occured).

Comment: @april21: What do you mean with isn't working? Is the list modified? Is the UI not updated? Do you get an exception? Are you sure you typed the exact same `String`s into all of your text fields? Do you get an exception?

Comment: It's not deleting the entry! yep, I'm positive. No exception!

Comment: @april21: Then you broke something else, since I tried it out and it worked for me. It's just more evidence you shouldn't take shortcuts when learning something.

Comment: It's not working for me - but I'll work on it more, I definitely agree @fabian! Many thanks for your fast help and candid advice. Would you have any recommendations where I could learn JavaFX more thoroughly from? websites/books or anything honestly

Comment: @april21: Since you didn't get the hint with "override equals", I'd recommend doing tutorials about polymorphism/interfaces, similar concepts, Collections (make sure you also sure you know about the importance of `equals` [and `hashCode`]), in case you don't know about that, then start with javafx. In my opinion the oracle tutorials about javafx are the best I could find, but you started with an **intermediate** tutorial, and that's not a good idea. Start with a beginner tutorial and **make sure you understand everything**. The javadoc is also a good place to find additional details.